# Sharing a link to Facebook directly with an intent?

Tags: android, facebook

I currently share links on facebook with the below code. Is it possible to specify the text to put in the "Say something about this..." field in the ShareLinkActivity (ie. is it possible to specify the text that goes in that field in the intent)? I'm looking for a solution, if any exists, that does not require the Facebook API

```
public void shareFacebook(String url) {
    try {

        Intent sendShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendShareIntent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity"); 
        sendShareIntent.setType("text/*");
        sendShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);           
        startActivityForResult(sendShareIntent, FACEBOOK_REQUEST_CODE);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
sendShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "something";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The "Say something about this..." field's value does not get to "something". Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is not a way to share text, only a single URL.

a known bug that facebook knows and does not want to fix, possibly because they want you to use their SDK

what i've done is branch the intent, so that everything besides facebook gets the String of text + URL, while facebook just shares the URL. not ideal.

heres a link showing how i branched if interested [Branching the Android Share Intent extras depending on which method they choose to share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450867/branching-the-android-share-intent-extras-depending-on-which-method-they-choose/14513635#14513635)

someone also came up with a very ugly workaround, where they passed string vars to a webpage URL they control, and dynamically rewrite the meta description (or content) of the page being shared to have the text you want to share. then the text is at least there in the share, although not in the facebook message area, but the URL preview. (can't find that example atm)