# Android - Chooser dialog for sharing -- different intents depending on application selected?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

I'd like to share different information depending on the application selected by the user.  For example, I'd like to send shorter text to Twitter than I do Gmail (otherwise, I go over in characters).  Is there anyway to achieve this?  Bonus question, is it possible to make hyperlinks via sharing via Gmail or SMS.  For example, "Download *here*"  where 'here' is a link instead of "Download by clicking the link below: http://..."

Current code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data));
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getTitle());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share this story"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the selected share target this could be interesting for you: [Branching the Android Share Intent extras depending on which method they choose to share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450867/branching-the-android-share-intent-extras-depending-on-which-method-they-choose)

Answer (score 0):

By using below code may helps you:

```
String shareText="Download <a href='[download link]'>here</a>";
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.toHtml(shareText));
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getTitle());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share this story"));
```

[Share Url Links and Texts into Social Networks (Facebook,Twitter and linkedin)](http://kalisandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/introduction-will-help-to-share-your.html)