# Android - Using dynamic text field for sharing using chooser dialog

Tags: android, twitter, share, android-sharing, socialshare

If the user chooses Twitter, I want to send an abbreviated text field (due to character limit).  From this SO post -- [Branching the Android Share Intent extras depending on which method they choose to share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450867/branching-the-android-share-intent-extras-depending-on-which-method-they-choose) -- I learned that I can implement targeted intents.  However, when I use the code below, a number of apps show as "Android System" and Twitter does not show up in the dialog.  I even removed the if block trying to catch Twitter, and it still did not appear.

```
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

    PackageManager pm = rootView.getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);
    for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList){

        String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        if(TextUtils.equals(packageName, TWITTER_PACKAGE_NAME)){
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data, "Twitter"));
        } else {
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getTitle());
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data));
        }

        targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);

    }

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1), "Share this story");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

I'm not really sure what's going on with the following:

```
Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1), "Share this story");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
```

In the SO post, `targetedShareIntents.remove(0)` was used although `targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1)` was proposed as a more reusable solution. Any help or explanations on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is value of `TWITTER_PACKAGE_NAME`?

Comment: `final String TWITTER_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.twitter.android";`

Answer (score 0):

I think `TextUtils.equals(packageName, TWITTER_PACKAGE_NAME)` can't find exactly `com.twitter.android` package name, so you need to try below code for match *Twitter* package name

```
if(packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.twitter")){
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data, "Twitter"));
    } else {
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getTitle());
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data));
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the problem.  It is finding the Twitter package (I set a breakpoint), and I actually tried that code as well.